# Display array of product in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, components, react-bootstrap-table

I am implementing a component called Table, imported from react-bootstrap. I am currently passing data from parent to child by arrays, but I am having difficulty writing arrays through the parent class, I do not know how to write code in this case

Here is my code in `index.js` in folder `src/components/table/index`

```
import React from 'react';
import {Table, Image} from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../Table/index.css';
import Button from '../Button/index';

const TableItem = ({productList}) => {
  const redirectToEdit = () => {
    console.log("Open edit form for me, please?")
  }

  const deleteProductItem = () => {
    console.log("The product has been deleted")
  }
  return(
    <Table striped bordered hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No. </th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {productList.map((product, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{product.id}</td>
            <td><Image src={product.image} /></td>
            <td>{product.name}</td>
            <td>{product.category}</td>
            <td>{product.price}</td>
            <td>
              <Button variant="success" onClick={redirectToEdit}>Edit</Button>
              <Button variant="danger" onClick={deleteProductItem}>Delete</Button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}

export default TableItem;
```

And here is my code in `app.js` folder `src/app.js`

```
<TableItem 
   productList={["1", "https://place-hold.it/100x150", "Black milk tea", "Milk Tea", "10000"]}
/>
```

IN above, I just **added 1 product, but it do not display** when I run, My problem is **how can I write many products** for this in `app.js` by **array**

Can anyone help me please, thank you so much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product list array should look like this:

```js
const productList=[
{
  id:"1",
  image:"https://place-hold.it/100x150",
  name:"Black milk tea",
  category:"Milk Tea",
  price:"10000"
},{
  id:"2",
  image:"https://place-hold.it/100x150",
  name:"Black milk tea",
  category:"Milk Tea",
  price:"10000"
}];
.
.
.
<TableItem productList={productList} />
```

Answer (score 1):

you must change two things in your code. The very first thing is its a dictionary that is passed to you TableItem so the code must be

```
const TableItem = (dict) => { 
    productList = dict.productList;
    // then your remaining code..
```

And when rendering it you need to pass productList as following:

```
<TableItem productList={[{id:"1", image:"https://place-hold.it/100x150", name:"Black milk tea",category: "Milk Tea",price: "10000"}]} />
```

Now let me help you get your concept cleared, the very first thing is if u are accesing some properties using dot u must have a dictionary instead u just had a list as your productList, secondly every time in react u declare a function or a constructor class in Component u are passed with a dictionary generally people name it props.

Comment: Sorry i missed out something,  they key you are using must not be the index you can refer here https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

You should provide an array of objects. Try this

```
<TableItem     
productList={[
{"id":"1","image": "https://place-hold.it/100x150","name": "Black milk tea","category": "Milk Tea","price": "10000"}
]} />
```

You can provide multiple items like,

```
<TableItem     
productList={[
{"id":"1","image": "https://place-hold.it/100x150","name": "Black milk tea","category": "Milk Tea","price": "10000"},
{"id":"2","image": "https://place-hold.it/150x150","name": "Black milk tea 2","category": "Milk Tea 2","price": "10000"},
{"id":"3","image": "https://place-hold.it/230x150","name": "Black milk tea","category": "Milk Tea 3","price": "10000"}
]} />
```